# How to restrict public user access to s3 buckets or minIO?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I have got a question about minio or s3 policy. I am using a stand-alone minio server for my project. Here is the situation :

- There is only one admin account that receives files and uploads them to minio server.
- My Users need to access just their own uploaded objects. I mean another user is not supposed to see other people's object publicly (e.g. by visiting direct link in URL).
- Admin users are allowed to see all objects in any circumstances.

**1. How can i implement such policies for my project considering i have got my database for user authentication and how can i  combine them to authenticate the user.**

**2. If not what other options do i have here to ease the process ?**

Answer (score 1):

Communicate with your storage through the application. Do policy checks, authentication or authorization in the app and store/grab files to/from storage and make the proper response. I guess this is the only way you can have limitation on uploading/downloading files using Minio.
If you're using a framework like `Laravel` built in S3 driver works perfectly with Minio; Otherwise it's just matter of a HTTP call. Minio provides HTTP APIs.